# How to update a MySQL Database using a PHP form using MVC

Tags: php, mysql, forms, model-view-controller

I am doing a school project.

Here is a link to the project http://www.dsu-class.com/zito82/lab10/

I need to use the MVC model to code a PHP application. I've gotten all the steps done except for one. I was required to add an Update input button to the list of customers. From this input button I launch into the update form. When I submit this form it is supposed to update the customer data.

I am having two problems. I created the list of customers via a foreach loop and that assigns a customerID to each update button however once I pass through to the form I cannot pull the customerID to pass through with the form.

The second problem is that my form does not update the MYSQL database.

To be clear, I have to follow this MVC Structure. It would be much easier for me to build php files instead of functions but that is how I am supposed to do this.

Here is my code. I have the Controller listed first, the Model(s) second, and the view last.

```
<?php
require('../model/database.php');
require('../model/customer-db.php');

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
} else if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
} else {
    $action = 'display_customers';
}

if ($action == 'display_customers') {
    $customers = get_customers();
    include '../view/customer-list.php';
}
else if ($action == 'view_customerData') {
    $customerID = $_GET['customerID'];
    view_customerData($customerID);
    include '../view/customer-information.php';
}
else if ($action == 'update_customer') {
    $customerID = $_POST['customerID']; $firstName = $_POST['firstName']; $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $address = $_POST['address']; $city = $_POST['city']; $state = $_POST['state']; $postalCode = $_POST['postalCode'];
    $countryCode = $_POST['countryCode']; $phone = $_POST['phone']; $email = $_POST['email'];

    update_customer($customerID, $firstName, $lastName, $address, $city, $state, $postalCode, $countryCode, $phone, $email);
    $customers = get_customers();
    include '../view/customer-list.php';
}
else if ($action == 'delete_customer') {
    $customerID = $_POST['customerID'];
    delete_customer($customerID);
    $customers = get_customers();
    include '../view/customer-list.php';
}
else if ($action == 'under-construction') {
    include('../under-construction.php');
} else

?>
```

Model containing my function calls for the Controller

```
<?php
require_once('database.php');

function get_customers() {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customers
              ORDER BY lastName";
    $customers = $db->query($query);
    return $customers;
}

function delete_customer($customerID) {
    global $db;
    $query = "DELETE FROM customers
              WHERE customerID = '$customerID'";
        $db->exec($query);
}

function view_customerData ($customerID) {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customers
              WHERE customerID = '$customerID'";
    $customerData = $db->query($query);
    $customerData = $customerData->fetch();
    return $customerData;
}

function update_customer($customerID, $firstName, $lastName, $address, $city, $state, $postalCode, $countryCode, $phone, $email) {
    global $db;
    $query = "UPDATE customers
              SET
                  firstName = '$firstName', lastName = '$lastName', address = '$address', city = '$city', state = '$state',
                  postalCode = '$postalCode', countryCode = '$countryCode', phone = '$phone', email = '$email'
              WHERE customerID = '$customerID' ";
    $db->exec($query);

}

?>
```

My views

Customer List View

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <h2> Customer List </h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email Address</th>
                    <th>Country Code</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($customers as $customer) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo ($customer['lastName'] . "," . $customer['firstName']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo strtolower($customer['email']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $customer['countryCode']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="." method="get">
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="view_customerData" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="customerID" value="<?php echo $customer['customerID']; ?>" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="." method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete_customer" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="customerID" value="<?php echo $customer['customerID']; ?>" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
         </div>
    </div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Customer Update Form View

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <h2> Update Customer </h2>
            <form action="../customer-manager/index.php" method="post" id="aligned">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_customer" />
                <input type="hidden" name="customerID" id="customerID" />
                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" autofocus></br>
                <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName"></br>
                <label for="address">Address:</label>
                <input type="text" name="address" id="address"></br>
                <label for="city">City:</label>
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city"></br>
                <label for="state">State:</label>
                <input type="text" name="state" id="state"></br>
                <label for="postalCode">Postal Code:</label>
                <input type="text" name="postalCode" id="postalCode"></br>
                <label for="countryCode">Country Code:</label>
                <input type="text" name="countryCode" id="countryCode"></br>
                <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
                <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone"></br>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></br>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></br>
                <label for="update_customer"> </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Update Customer">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Well, for one thing... all of these variables require quoting `lastName = $lastName, address = $address, city = $city, state = $state,
                  postalCode = $postalCode, countryCode = $countryCode, phone = $phone, email = $email
              WHERE customerID = $customerID";` just as you did for `firstName = '$firstName'`. Error checking would have signaled syntax errors.

Comment: Yea, I originally eliminated all variables except firstName to try to narrow down the update, and I didn't put the quotes back. Even with the single variable I still couldn't get it to work. I have a feeling it is something stupid simple.

Comment: First thing I can see is that your hidden `customerID` input in the update form has no value. Also, you're not assigning the return value of `view_customerData()` to anything. I'd go with `$customer = view_customerData($customerID);`. Then you can use `$customer` in your `customer-information.php` view

Comment: Which MySQL API are you using to connect with, `mysqli_` or PDO? Seems like PDO.

Comment: Your `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="view_customerData" />` in Customer List View is pointing to `view_customerData` that should be `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_customer" />` Try that. If it works, I'll make it an answer. Lord knows I should; I've only been starting at it for 20 mins. lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think it's meant to work that way. They click the `Update` button which runs the `view_customerData` action. OP hasn't explained it clearly but I presume the update form is in `customer-information.php`. It's pretty clear there's no POST data in the form in the list view to pass to `update_customer`

Comment: @Phil OP has `else if ($action == 'update_customer') {...}` which they say the update isn't working. Saw that in their HTML source from the link, in regards to the hidden input for "update".

Comment: ...being `<form action="." method="get">
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="view_customerData" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="customerID" value="1118" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Update" />`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yup, and that action is triggered by the form in the last code snippet (*"Customer Update Form View"*). It's not working because there's no `customerID` value in that form (see [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552299/how-to-update-a-mysql-database-using-a-php-form-using-mvc#comment47256433_29552299))

Comment: @Phil It's a tricky one for sure.

Comment: There's all together too much code in this question. That being said, I'm fairly confident I've pinpointed the problem

Comment: @Phil True. Which is why it's best to build a house "brick by brick", rather than hoping the building will stand up and the lights will go on and won't break once it's dropped onto the foundation, fallen as one big piece. ;-) Once one works, the rest will follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will solve your problem but I'm making the assumption that the form you've labelled as *"Customer Update Form View"* is in `customer-information.php`.

In whatever file is at the top of your question, for the `view_customerData` action...

```
else if ($action == 'view_customerData') {
    $customerID = $_GET['customerID'];
    $customer = view_customerData($customerID); // note the return value is now assigned
    include '../view/customer-information.php';
}
```

Then, in `customer-information.php`, pre-fill the form with data. The main thing missing is the customer ID...

```
<form action="../customer-manager/index.php" method="post" id="aligned">

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_customer">
<input type="hidden" name="customerID" id="customerID" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($customer['customerID']) ?>">

<label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($customer['firstName']) ?>" autofocus></br>

<label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($customer['lastName']) ?>"></br>

<!-- etc -->
```

Now, I highly recommend you start using prepared statements with parameter binding instead of concatenating / interpolating values directly into your SQL queries.

Comment: that worked, can't believe I missed assigning the return value. I knew it was something obvious. Thanks

Comment: Wait to go Phil (the answerer) ;-)